# Process file descriptors and SIGKILL signal behavior

Tags: c, linux, signals

I've little question about file descriptors and signals on Linux.

```
are all file descriptors close when process terminated by SIGKILL signal?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  The kernel closes all still-open file descriptors when any process is terminated for any reason.